Parallel matrix multiplication. As the number of threads increases, execution time increases
public class Main {
    public static int P = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < P; i++) {
            Thread Ti = new MyThread(i);
            Ti.start();
        }
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    int N = 200;
    int P = 10;
    int H = N/P;
    private long time;
    private int threadId;
    public MyThread(int id) {
        this.threadId = id;
    }
    int [][] MX = new int[N][N];
    int [][] MR = new int[N][N];
    int [][] MXMR = new int[N][N];

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                MX[i][j] = 1;
                MR[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        if (threadId == 0){
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        for (int i = H*threadId; i < H*(threadId + 1); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                MXMR[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    MXMR[i][j] += MX[i][k] * MR[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(threadId == 0){
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        }


    }
}

I have a java code that multiplies matrices in parallel. But as the number of threads increases, the calculation time also increases, although the value of N remains unchanged. For example, for N=200 and P=1 the time was 16 ms, and for N=200 and P=10 the time was 41ms, although there are 12 threads on my computer

Your CPU has some physical cores (for example 4 core) and if it has hyperthreading, maybe you have 8, 16 or ... threads. In linux run cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vendor_id | wc -l to determine that (say it N_THREADS). You can best results with n_threads <= N_THREADS. More threads than that may result in decreased performance.

check the question How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java? ||| some problems: 1) number of cores see previous comment; 2) timing only ONE thread; 3) timing only ONE SINGLE run; ( 4) maybe some error like forgetting to change both variable P )

you are creating P threads to multiply matrices in parallel. As P increases, the operating system needs to spend more time managing these threads, which can lead to increased overhead and potentially slower performance.also your thread allocation seems not optimal you can try dividing the matrices into smaller blocks and assigning each block multiplication to a thread. This can reduce contention and improve parallelism

but when N is large enough (1500), the situation is better, but there are still situations when, for example, with P = 8, the execution time is better than with P = 10.

Perhaps P=8 reflects your cpu cores or threads count.

No, i have 6 cores and 12 threads
